# saving NSString and then reading it back

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hey all, this should be a simple task but for some reason i am making it harder... I am trying to save some text from an XML file to a NSString. But when i debug it, the string says "Out of scope".

Here is my code:

in my .h file:

```
 @interface RootViewController : UIViewController<MBProgressHUDDelegate> {
     NSString *thePW;   
 }
```

and my .m file:

```
 NSString *thePW;
 ...
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 ...
    if(e == nil){
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        thePW = response; // <-- this is where it has "Out of scope"
        [response release];
    }
 }

 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
     if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
     {
        if (thePW == @"0000")
        {
           NSLog(@"correct!");
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also try:

```
thePW = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response];   // to assign the string value.
```

and
 while comparing strings:

```
(thePW isEqualToString @"0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the redeclaration of thePW in your .m file

Also, if you want to keep the value of response in thePW be sure to retain it as well.

Comment: Took out the redeclaring in the .m file but it still has the "Out of Scope" on it when i check it in the IF()...

I also tried to retain it using this: @property (nonatomic,retain)  NSString *thePW; but i still get the same "Out of Scope".

Comment: If you made it a property, assign it with `self.thePW = response;` so the setter method is called.

Comment: drawnonward: doing that it gives me the error of "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[RootViewController thePW]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b04880'"